# font with graphic "blackspace" character

Tags: special-characters

I'm looking for a font which contains a graphic character which is (essentially), the space character, inverted. I'm looking for a graphic character equivalent to the largest-possible solid-black box. The closest I have been able to find is Wingings 2 character 162, but that doesn't fill the entire available character space. When I insert two consecutive Wingdings 2 162 characters, there is still appreciable whitespace between them when displayed or printed. Does anyone know of a black-box font/character which would fill all available character space?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What problem are you trying to solve (or cause?)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) site.

Answer (score 0):

All characters are going to have whitespace between them, or they would be unreadable. This is called "kerning". You can adjust the kerning and line-height in whatever program you are using to send the malicious fax, if you want to be sure to use the maximum amount of toner per page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating your own font using a software package [like this](http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html) or [like this](http://www.fontlab.com/)? You could edit the space character to be a solid black square. But as Chris McCall mentioned, you may still have space between characters of any size due to kerning applied by the layout engine that draws the fonts.

You other option is to owner draw your own text and programmatically replacing spaces with black boxes. You would have complete control over kerning and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you were looking for, but...

I was looking for the same thing, since I wanted to create a "textbox" when I wanted to write text using the spritefont, but I never knew how long the total string was going to be, so I wanted something that I could "write" in the same location right before the string with a contrasting color which could be expected to be as long as the string it needed to encompass. That being the case, try:

Webdings - character 103.
I tried lining them up and there wasn't even any space in between. Perfect.